# timediff not working with date_format in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, time, mysqli

I've made a query that calculates the `total_time1` from 2 other fields called `time_in` and `time_out` using `timediff(time_out, time_in) AS total_time1`.

Now, I want to convert that time into a better format instead of the usual `hh:mm:ss` so in the same query I did `DATE_FORMAT(total_time1, '%l:%i') AS total_time2`, but for some reason it doesn't work whenever I input a new time in and out.

This is the query:

```
$sql="SELECT 
        DATE_FORMAT(time_in, '%l:%i %p') AS time_in,
        DATE_FORMAT(time_out, '%l:%i %p') AS time_out,
        timediff(time_out, time_in) AS total_time1,
        DATE_FORMAT(total_time1, '%l:%i') AS total_time2,
      FROM $table";

$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
    <td><?php echo $row['time_in']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['time_out']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['total_time1']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['total_time2']; ?></td>
}
```

I'm displaying everything (including time in, out, totaltime1 and totaltime2) on a large table on it's own page. `total_time1` works like I said, but `total_time2` displays nothing. No errors or anything. What am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use an alias you made in the same query

you have to write it again like this

```
$sql="SELECT 
        DATE_FORMAT(time_in, '%l:%i %p') AS time_in,
        DATE_FORMAT(time_out, '%l:%i %p') AS time_out,
        timediff(time_out, time_in) AS total_time1,
        DATE_FORMAT(timediff(time_out, time_in), '%l:%i') AS total_time2
      FROM $table";
```

Also, if you want to format time,

you should not use `DATE_FORMAT` but `TIME_FORMAT` instead

like this

```
$sql="SELECT 
            TIME_FORMAT(time_in, '%l:%i %p') AS time_in,
            TIME_FORMAT(time_out, '%l:%i %p') AS time_out,
            timediff(time_out, time_in) AS total_time1,
            TIME_FORMAT(timediff(time_out, time_in), '%l:%i') AS total_time2
          FROM $table";
```

[Here's](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) the documentation about all the date and time functions in MySQL

Comment: Everything now appears as "12:00". Proper format, but for some reason it doesn't show the proper time difference.

Comment: Do time_in and time_out are datetime type?

Comment: total_time1 displays fine in hh:mm:ss. total_time2 seems to display everything in 12:00 format, while others are left blank. Can't seem to find any pattern.

Comment: You can find all the formats here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use DATE_FORMAT to format time but TIME_FORMAT. I will update my answer

Comment: PROGRESS AT LAST! Ok it seems to be working now. There's a weird bug where it doesn't really work that well if you go from AM to PM but for the most part everything seems ok.

Comment: Ok I figured it out. I changed `'%l:%i'` to `'%k:%i'` and it doesn't have that issue with AM/PM anymore.

Comment: Yes `TIME_FORMAT(timediff(time_out, time_in), '%k:%i') AS total_time2`

Comment: Try to use it for the others and try this instead `TIME_FORMAT(timediff(TIME_FORMAT(time_out, '%l:%i %p'), TIME_FORMAT(time_in, '%l:%i %p'), '%l:%i') as total_time2`

Comment: What would be the benefit of this? Everything works with the updated query now.

Answer (score 0):

You can't self-reference the column. You also had an extra comma, which I assume was a typo.

You need something like this:

```
$sql="SELECT time_in, time_out, total_time1, DATE_FORMAT(total_time1, '%l:%i') AS total_time2
FROM (SELECT 
        DATE_FORMAT(time_in, '%l:%i %p') AS time_in,
        DATE_FORMAT(time_out, '%l:%i %p') AS time_out,
        timediff(time_out, time_in) AS total_time1
      FROM $table) a";
```